# How do I pass a param to db.exec

Tags: postgresql, go

Consider the db.Exec statement,

> db.Exec("INSERT INTO $1 values($2,$3,to_timestamp($4),var1,var2,var3,var4)

^^ works however if I want to do something like

> db.Exec("INSERT INTO table_name_$1 values($2,$3,to_timestamp($4),var1,var2,var3,var4)

It doesn't work, $1 gets appended to the table name instead of the values of $1, how do I add it to the query ?

Comment: Just format the table name part manually with `%s`, making sure to escape and validate the name properly. Of course, passing parametric table names is not always such a great idea, which is probably why the library doesn't handle this case.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer thanks the %s works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say the first example works, one solution is to pass in the full table name as a parameter, doing the string concatenation beforehand:

```
db.Exec("INSERT INTO $1 values($2,$3)", "table_name_"+tbl, "this", "that")
```

You could also format the string manually with `fmt.Sprintf` and `%s`, as suggested in the comments.

#### Prepared statements

I am a little surprised that your first example works, as this is not valid syntax in Postgres. If you create a prepared statement with the table name as a parameter, it returns a syntax error:

```
# PREPARE fooplan (text, bool, numeric) AS
    INSERT INTO $1 VALUES($2, $3);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 2:     INSERT INTO $1 VALUES($2, $3);
```

Whereas the second example you gave also appends `$1` to the name of the table, so the library is behaving correctly:

```
# PREPARE fooplan (text, bool, numeric) AS
    INSERT INTO table_name_$1 VALUES($2, $3);
ERROR:  relation "table_name_$1" does not exist
LINE 2:     INSERT INTO table_name_$1 VALUES($2, $3);
```

So in your first example the library might be acting in your favor, but this is probably not something you should rely on too heavily.

The safest long-term solution is probably to use `fmt.Sprintf`, with the necessary escaping, to format the table name, and then use that in the `Exec` call:

```
sql := fmt.Sprintf(`INSERT INTO table_name_%s values($1,$2,to_timestamp($3))`, tbl)
db.Exec(sql, params...)
```

Comment: Thanks, formatted the string using %s, actually the $1 refereed to an argument, forgot to add that :/